# Accessing Ingress Controller using Host, tls and IP

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-traffic-manager

I am using AKS and I need to make the ingress controller accessible by host and IP (to be accessed traffic manager), I am using Nginx Ingress rules as below:
for example using https://foo.bar.com and https://14.15.16.222

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.bar.com
    secretName: foo-secret
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders-x
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the network policy in AKS. It can help you to control access to the pod.

Comment: Hi Charles, I found a workaround below using rules. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below configuration did the trick eventhough I get a certificate error with the IP access.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.bar.com
    secretName: foo-secret
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders-x
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echoheaders-x
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```